# Big delay executing sound on iPad and Android

Tags: android, jquery, ipad, delay, soundmanager2

I want to play a sound when the user click on a image. I'm using SoudManager plugin.

Here you can check what I'm doing:

```
soundManager.setup({
        url: 'swf',
        onready: function() {
            soundCarro = soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'soundCarro',
                url: 'sound/carro_camona.mp3'
            });
            soundMoto = soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'soundMoto',
                url: 'sound/moto_camona.mp3'
            });
            soundNautico = soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'soundNautico',
                url: 'sound/nautico_camona.mp3'
            });
        }
    });
```

As you can see, I create 3 sound objects (soundCarro, soundMoto and soundNautico).

Here the action, where when the user clicks on it, the scrollTo function is called:

```
<img id="ca" class="ca logo" onclick="scrollTo('secao-carros',true);" src="images/svg/CAhome.svg">
```

Here you can see the scrollTo function:

```
function scrollTo(target,sound){
    if(sound){

        var delay = 0;

        if(target == 'secao-carros'){
            soundCarro.play();
            delay = 700;
            duration = 750;
        }

        if(target == 'secao-motos'){
            soundMoto.play();
            delay = 900;
            duration = 750;
        }

        if(target == 'secao-nauticos'){
            soundNautico.play();
            delay = 850;
            duration = 2000;
        }

        $('html, body').delay(delay).animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+target).offset().top }, {duration: duration});
    }else{
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+target).offset().top }, {duration: 750});
    }
}
```

As you can see, in this function I execute the sound object created (ex: soundNautico.play();).

The issue is that on iPad and Android devices this sound gets a big delay to execute, but in desktop browsers it works perfect!

How can I prevent this delay?

Answer (score 1):

That's because desktop browsers will preload the audio so when you call `.play()` the browser will begin playing it immediately because it has already buffered some (if not all) of the audio.

I know that iOS and most other mobile browsers will A) only allow you to play a single audio file at a time, B) not allow you to cache audio at all, and C) only allow you initialize/play an audio object if the user physically initiated the action **on the same call stack**. So you're basically out of luck if you don't want the delay.

**Edit:** You could add an event listener to the audio and only trigger the scroll after the audio had buffered. However, you cannot load more than one sound at a time.

```
audio.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {
  doScroll();
  audio.play();
}, false);
```

```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But there isn't a way to preload in iOS? Something like "just show the image if the sound is loaded"?